# commutators and characters

Tags: gr.group-theory, characters

Let $x$ be an element in a finite group and let $\chi$ be an irreducible complex character of $G$. It is well-known that
$$|\chi(x)|^2=\frac{\chi(1)}{|G|}\sum_{z\in G}\chi([x,z]).$$ The easiest proof I know is from Patrick Gallagher. There are various generalizations of this for products of commutators.

I am wondering if there is an analogous generalization when the summation is NOT over commutators $[x,z]$ but over commutators $[x,z,z]$.

Comment: The trick with commutators is that if I sum [x,z] over all z and then i get up to a scalar x.a where a is the class sum of the conjugacy class of the inverse of x.  Now if I sum over all elements of the class of x I get up to a scalar ba where b is the class sum for x and a is the class sum for x inverse. Since a,b are in the center of the group algebra and $\chi/\chi(1)$ is a central character we can get your formula. The same idea works for products of commutators. But I don't think summing [x,z,z] first over z and then over the class of x has an easy description as a product in the center.

Comment: Ctd... So a formula will be harder to get.